# Jquery hover selection not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a gallery that contains 10 images with same class. I want to use hover effect for each image separately using jquery and css3. I have used a way to select images and apply animation. But If i hover over one image, I have seen that animation effect is applied to all images.

My main DIV id name `#continer` and all images id `#image_id`

```
$("#image_id").hover(function () {
    $("#image_id").addClass("start_animation")
});
```

Comment: Where is your markup? This is meaningless without some HTML to bounce it off of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is an `id` has to be unique. Instead you need to select the classname for each image. Or you can use the parent and select the `img` tag from there:

```
$('#container').on('mousein', 'img', function(){
    $(this).addClass('start_animation');
});
```

In the above example I've used an event delegation `mouseover` on the `#container` and it will automatically apply this event to the `img` selector.

Now typically the `hover()` function takes 2 function parameters for the mousein/mouseout event. So to get rid of the class after `mouseout` you'll have to bind that event as well.

```
$('#container').on('mouseout', 'img', function(){
    $(this).removeClass('start_animation');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#image_id").hover(function () {
 $(this).addClass("start_animation")
});
```

Try above code.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do this:

```
$("#container").hover(function (e) {
 $(e.target).addClass("start_animation")
});
```